# Calling a text box value when the progress bar finishes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am new to C#.
Just doing my first project.
This is my code.
I just want to fill the textbox once the progress bar finish loading.
But its not working now.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing worong.
My code is as below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Start();
       // int n = timer1.Interval;
        int m = progressBar1.Value;

        if(m==0)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "test";
        }
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
int progressVal=0;   
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Start();
        // int n = timer1.Interval;

    }

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
        progressVal= progressBar1.Value;

        if(progressVal==progressBar1.Maximum)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            textBox2.Text = "Loading done!";
        }
    }
```